# @property/@synthesize question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, properties, synthesizer

I'm going through all of my documentation regarding memory management and I'm a bit confused about something.

When you use @property, it creates getters/setters for the object:

.h:
    @property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *myString

.m:
    @synthesize myString

I understand that, but where I get confused is the use of self. I see different syntax in different blogs and books. I've seen:

```
myString = [NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hi there"];
```

or

```
self.myString = [NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hi there"];
```

Then in dealloc I see:

```
self.myString = nil;
```

or

```
[myString release];
```

or

```
self.myString = nil;
[myString release];
```

On this site, someone stated that using self adds another increment to the retain count? Is that true, I haven't seen that anywhere.

Do the automatic getters/setters that are provided autorelease?

Which is the correct way of doing all of this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are not using the dot syntax you are not using any setter or getter.

The next thing is, it depends on how the property has been declared.

Let's assume something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Article *article;
...
@synthesize article;
```

**Assigning** something to article with

```
self.article = [[Article alloc] init];
```

will overretain the instance given back by alloc/init and cause a leak. This is because the setter of article will retain it and will release any previous instance for you.

So you could rewrite it as:

```
self.article = [[[Article alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Doing this

```
article = [[Article alloc] init];
```

is also ok, but could involve a leak as article may hold a reference to an instance already. So freeing the value beforehand would be needed:

```
[article release];
article = [[Article alloc] init];
```

---

**Freeing memory** could be done with

```
[article release];
```

or with

```
self.article = nil;
```

The first one does access the field directly, no setters/getters involved. The second one sets nil to the field by using a setter. Which will release the current instance, if there is one before setting it to nil.

**This construct**

```
self.myString = nil; 
[myString release];
```

is just too much, it actually sends release to nil, which is harmless but also needless.

**You just have to mentally map hat using the dot syntax is using accessor methods:**

```
self.article = newArticle
// is
[self setArticle:newArticle];
```

and

```
myArticle = self.article;
// is
myArticle = [self article];
```

---

*Some suggestions on reading, all official documents by Apple:*

**The Objective-C Programming Language**

- [Dot Syntax](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW17)
- [Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1)

**Memory Management Programming Guide**

- [Object Ownership and Disposal](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB)
- [Using Accessor Methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW4)

Comment: Specifically, some would say that using `self.article = nil` in you `dealloc` would be "risky" because `self` might already be partially `dealloc`:ed. I say "meh" and use properties wherever i can.

Comment: One reason to not use self.property = nil in dealloc is because if another object is using KVO to watch that property then side effects can occur if the watching object tries to access already released objects etc...

Comment: @Nick: +1 for the gr8 answer. What more could anyone ask for?

Comment: @Nick: too bad i could only vote up once :( Its just an awesome answer

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `retain` setter, you're creating something like this:

```
- (void)setString:(NSString *)someString {
    if (someString != string) {
        [string release];
        [someString retain];
        string = someString;
    }
}
```

If you don't use the setter, the new value is not getting that retain—you don't "own" that string, and because it's all references, if the original string is released, you might be facing a null reference, which will lead to an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Using the setter ensures that your class now has a copy of that value—so yes, it does increment the retain count of the new value. (Note that using the getter is a convention of OOP—that outsiders should not be able to directly touch the ivar. Also in your getter you can modify the value, maybe returning an NSArray when your ivar is an NSMutableArray, for example).

You shouldn't `autorelease` in a setter—Apple has used it in their sample code, but a thing to keep in mind is that setters are called a lot—millions of times, potentially. All of those objects are going into the same autorelease pool, so unless you create your own and/or regularly flush it, you'll have a ton of elements in your pool, all unneeded but still taking up RAM. Much better to simply `release`.

As for dealloc, trace back through that setter. If you send a `release` directly, it's obvious—you release that object. But if you write `self.string = nil;`, what you're doing is this:

1. The nil value is not the same, so you enter the `if` block
2. **You release the old value—what you want to do**
3. You `retain` nil: messages to nil do nothing, and you don't crash
4. You set nil, which doesn't take up any memory, to the string, which is now effectively empty

As a matter of convention, I use `release` in my `dealloc` method, because `release` seems more final, and `dealloc` is the final method call your object will receive. I use `self.string = nil;` in viewDidUnload and the memory warning methods.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Nick's answer - synthesized getters/setters don't provide autorelease (btw, what's the big idea of doing this? Well, you can use getter as a factory, but it's not a common way in Objective C).

> Then in dealloc I see:
>
> self.myString = nil;
>
> or
>
> [myString release];
>
> or
>
> self.myString = nil; [myString
>   release];

In dealloc it doesn't really matter which form of release you're using. But the good way is to nil your fields when releasing them :) I prefer to use `self.myString = nil;` in dealloc

Comment: I too prefer using the self.myString = nil in dealloc.

Comment: I Have a doubt.If myString has a retainCount of 1 and we call self.myString = nil; is it ok to do like that. Or should we release and then set it to nil.

Comment: @raj2raaz: If myString property is declared as (retain) than `self.myString = nil;` and `[myString release]; myString = nil;` actually are same.